# Reading a low-voltage digital signal from a device using Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: circuit-design, raspberry-pi

I'm a software engineer without much/any electrical engineering knowledge. For a project I'm working on, I need a compute device to detect the state of a separate audio device. The audio device is a a drive-thru restaurant audio system. Currently, I'm planning to use a Raspberry Pi 5 as the compute device.

I found that the physical audio appliance has a pinout including a ground pin and a signal pin. When the device is in the state that I'd like to detect, there's a voltage of 0.6V across the ground and signal pins. This is below the Raspberry Pi's threshold for 'high' signal in GPIO so I don't think it can be directly detected by GPIO. I verified using a multimeter that I can use a [2N2222A transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf) to amplify the signal to a voltage that the raspberry pi can read. I verified this by connecting the transistor's Emitter-Base-Collector as follows:

- Emitter: Connected to 'Ground' on the audio device.
- Base: Connected to the +0.6V signal pin on the audio device
- Collector: Connected to negative terminal of a multimeter. Positive terminal of multimeter connected to a +12V constant pin on the audio device.

In this configuration the multimeter reads 0V when the state is inactive and ~12V when it's active.

However, I'm reaching the limit of my electronics knowledge and have questions about what's the simplest way to integrate this signal to the Pi's GPIO pins:

1. Would the voltage differential "Ground" on the Raspberry Pi and the signal pin on the audio device also be +0.6V when the signal is active? (i.e. are the "grounds" on the two devices interchangeable?)
2. Assuming 'yes' to (1), if I connect the "emitter" to a GPIO input pin on the Pi, "base" to the 0.6V signal on the audio device, and "collector" to a 3.3V constant pin on the Pi; will I see a 'High' signal on the GPIO input pin when the 0.6V signal is active?
3. If 'no' to (1), I'm assuming I need more components -- e.g. I could use the transistor to amplify the signal and drive a relay, then use the relay to control the GPIO 3.3V input instead. It's a very low current, so I was hoping a relay is not necessary. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: What is the 'other' state that you wish to *distinguish* from the 0.6V state? We need more information on this 'signal'. A schematic and specifications would be ideal, but anything you have would be good. Also it is unclear whether you can tie the grounds together. That could depend on the entire system, and if we assume they cannot be tied together a more complex solution would result. On the other hand, if they actually can't be and they are tied together it could cause issues up to and including damage to some devices.

Comment: BTW, 600mV is not enough most likely to *reliably* drive a BJT. It could fail when it gets warm, for example. Not a problem this time of year in the Northern Hemisphere, but summer is coming.

Comment: Is the audio system output actually a steady DC level of 0.6 V, or is it an AC signal that happens to have a 0.6 V average value when you read it on a digital multimeter? That will make a difference in how you detect it, or whether you need any more components to do it reliably. Set the DMM to 'AC' and read again. How fast must the Pi respond to the audio device entering/leaving this state you want to detect? So many details to handle to make sure it does what you want, reliably. That 'can you connect the grounds' question is rather important for component count.

Comment: In the 'other'/inactive state, my multimeter reads 0V across the signal and ground pins. Thank you for the note about 600mV being insufficient to reliably drive a BJT.

Comment: The only real diagram I have of the audio board is on page 117 of this PDF: https://www.hme.com/techPdfs/400G733F.pdf - the relevant signal is "/A1 talk", pin J1,2. There's very little information about the details of the signal. Thanks for the note about possible AC voltage, I'll check that